# How can I id this celestial without data?

Tags: identify-this-object

Anecdotal. Also, I'm using the term 'celestial' loosely; to mean something shiny in the skies.

I'm based out of Nagpur in Central India. Sleeping outdoors on account of summer over the last few days I've made a weird observation. No matter what time it is, there is a fairly bright body visible in the NNW skies at an elevation of perhaps 20 degrees. From what little I gather a GSO object would be really dim, or even invisible. A LEO couldn't be in GSO unless it was in powered flight. I'm utterly flummoxed. The only reason I haven't seen it before is because earlier in life I would sleep outdoors on the balcony where this particular field of view is blocked by other structures around. Sleeping on the ground floor there is a field of view not available on the first floor. Adjacent buildings blocking the view on the first floor also act as a reference that the position of this object has not changed no matter what time of the night it is.

My location (from Google Maps) is 21.17103958702249, 79.08452532230748
The general direction where this object is visible is due 21.171644779275333, 79.08410335986589

How can I id this object?

Comment: "[...] that the position of this object has not changed no matter what time of the night it is." then the object is not astronomical in nature.

Comment: It's still up there at night shining brighter than many other objects around. By definition 'astronomy' would deal with stars alone. However there are also any number of human artifacts up there now.

Comment: Can you describe it in relation to the position of the "big dipper" (Ursa Major) which would be in that general region of the sky at that time.

Comment: I can't view Big Dipper, and this object concurrently. There's a canopy overhead and around which blocks out lots of the sky. In general though, since this is NNW - Big Dipper rotates past this setting further West of it after starting well in the East.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal in case of real time simulation is Stellarium software or an excellent android app like Sky safari.

Comment: There's no need to sign your answers, as this is automatically shown.  Feel free to fill out your user profile with your degree and any other infomation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying Stellarium Web ; there're too many stars as I zoom into the general direction.